# What does this line mean in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I dont really get this line of code.

```
With Worksheets("SKU2PCA")
  .Range(Cells(SKU2PCA_New_RowNum + 1, SKU2PCA_StartBkt_ColNum), Cells(SKU2PCA_New_RowNum + PCACount, SKU2PCA_Last_ColNum)).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(RC1&RC2,BOM!C4:C5,2,FALSE)*SKU2PCA_Staging!R" & SKU2PCA_Last_RowNum + 1 & ""
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"

    End With
```

I am understanding that it means like

RC1&RC2 : This row 1st column and This row 2nd Column
Find for the Rc1& Rc2 in the BOM worksheet in the ranges of C4 to C5
and obtain the 2nd column value with exact matching.

But the *SKU2PCA_Staging onwards is what i dont get it

SKU2PCA_Staging is a another worksheet with table and SKU2PCA_Last_RowNum is an Int value.

Thanks!

Comment: appears that it's a UDF (User Defined Function). From the name of it appears that it grabs the last row in that worksheet.

Comment: `CTRL+F` to search for `SKU2PCA_New_RowNum` in `Current Project`.

Answer (score 0):

`"=VLOOKUP(RC1&RC2,BOM!C4:C5,2,FALSE)*SKU2PCA_Staging!R" & SKU2PCA_Last_RowNum + 1 & ""`

The above is a multiplication of two values. The first is `VLOOKUP(RC1&RC2,BOM!C4:C5,2,FALSE)`, the second `SKU2PCA_Staging!R" & SKU2PCA_Last_RowNum + 1`